Credit Card Cash Back Points & Balance Transfers
If I charge a transaction on a credit card with a cash back/points features, and then eventually B/T that, or some arbitrary, amount over to another card, what happens to the cash back points on 1st card?  i.e. Do I still get to keep the cash back credit/points?

Cash them out beforehand?

Interesting...maybe...although if then are going to claw back points for >>any<< reason, that likely might just leave me with a negative cash back/point balance that gets paid off next time I transact?

Why might they claw some of it back?  (1) Returned merchandise. (2) Fraud. (3) ???.  And if they do… pay it.  Money is fungible, so put it aside for a couple of months, just in case.

Easy! Don't use credit cards! Wow think of the brainpower I just saved you. Also, eventually you get to log in to experian and they'll call you "unscorable", which feels as good as drugs

A balance transfer is just a payment from the new card company, it shouldn't affect rewards earned. Balance transfers also don't close the account, so any sign-up bonuses that require the account to remain open will not be affected either.
I'm not aware of any card that requires carrying a balance to qualify for rewards. Confirm specific terms/conditions of your card.

You will certainly get the reward on the first card. You will almost certainly not get the reward on the second card.
If you look at the details of your credit agreement, you will see that some categories of transaction are excluded from the reward offer, and "cash-equivalent transactions" and transfers are usually among those categories; only purchases are rewarded. Even if the cash transfer fee would cover them, the companies do not wish to encourage churning of money between accounts.
But this really depends on the individual credit agreement. Read your fine print. It's possible you have an exception.
Finding credit cards which allow reward points on cash transfers would be a "shopping question", and out of scope for this Stack. The answer would change too often for it to be a useful reference for others, and you can do that search as easily as we can.

This is a two credit card scenario.  I guess I sorta hoped that since card 1 already made their money on the transaction/interchange fee(s), and that that was what was being passed back to customer for cash-back style reward, that BTing it out to card 2 (which to me seems little different than making a payment on card 1) still leaves card 1 with fees/interchange from original transaction(s).

I think the OP is asking about transferring balance from card to card while keeping the rewards on the original card. If the new card rewards transfer balances then there's definitely an opportunity to double-dip.

Transferring balance will not remove the points earned on the first card. But I believe banks will not let you gain points on the second card this way, specifically to prevent double dipping.

Unless waived under a promotion, banks charge a balance transfer fee of 3-5%. That's generally more than a purchase. They can afford the rewards.

@user71659: response has been folded into my updated answer. Being able to afford it, and wishing to pay it, are not the same thing.

The conclusion here is correct, but not because it's a "cash-equivalent transaction".  It's because a balance transfer is not a purchase, and most credit cards earn rewards on purchases.

Valid; updating.

I'm bemused by the combination of votes on this answer.  It would be nice to know why the downvotes were made. Not important, since I honestly don't care a lot about the scoring and I am content with the answer, but it might be something a simple edit could fix.
